# What config option links a Wordpress database to its files?

Tags: wordpress, docker, virtualbox, docker-compose

I'm trying to restore my online Wordpress site to my localhost.

## Install

This little Dockerfile successfully downloads & runs Wordpress in a container on my machine:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: lkj
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 60001:3306
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - 60000:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: lkj
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/www/html
```

I can browse & install the default site on `0.0.0.0:60000` and explore the MySql database on `0.0.0.0:60001`.

## Restore files

Then I overwrite all my WP files in my wp-content folder with files from my site backup.  Everything still works. (The wp-config isn't changed).

## Restore db

Then I delete the `wordpress` database and create a new one, and run my online site's backup script. All tables are successfully created.

But now when I browse to `0.0.0.0:60000` I get the message`This site can’t be reached. 0.0.0.0 refused to connect.`

## Why is it broken?

Why is this?  **What settings do I need to check in the database?**  I tried looking in `wp_options` and changing the `home` and `site_url` settings but that didn't help.

## Update -------

I ran this on my db `update wordpress.wp_options set option_value='http://0.0.0.0:60000'  where option_name in ('siteurl', 'home')` (http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-wordpress/ said it might help).

I can now log in to `wp-admin` but the main site error hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following query against your MySql database:

```
update wordpress.wp_options set option_value='http://0.0.0.0:60000'  where option_name in ('siteurl', 'home')
```

Then close your browser, reopen it, and open incognito mode and try browsing to `0.0.0.0:60000`.  If that fails, reopen and try browsing to `127.0.0.1:60000`, or finally `localhost:60000`.

As well as altering your database wp_options table you have to be careful with how your Docker network is set up (especially if you are on a VM already using either NAT or bridged connection), and remember that most browsers won't clear their cache and retry the site even if it now works.

Answer (score 0):

change wp-config.php file in which you have to set localhost's,

```
DB_NAME
DB_USER
DB_PASSWORD
DB_HOST
```

Comment: They look correct already (i.e. the match the Dockerfile) - `wordpress`, `root`, `lkj`, `db`.  Also the file was not changed from the fresh install where it works (I overwrote only the `wp-content` files).

Comment: yes, if your DB / host / user /password all credential are same as server website then no need to change it ..